# Who is this person speaking for?

Tags: meaning

In the conversation below, I am unclear with regards to who person 4 is speaking for. That is whether they are speaking for themselves, or the other 1000 people that have been brought in to help.

To provide some context: the 1000 (lower ranking and weaker) people have been brought in to help clear the way to their destination, where the people who are currently talking will then take over and continue the fight.

> Person 1: １０００人ってＢとかＤとかだろ？ いくら野外での戦闘とはいえちょっと荷が重いよね。
>
> Person 2: 陸空軍の支援もある、他人の心配なんて暇ないよ。
>
> Person 3: ロボには頼れず、 航空機は撃墜されるのが今日で実証済み。敵１匹の強さも規格外。 多くの死者が出ますよ。
>
> Person 4: **そういう戦いに身を置いたんだ。覚悟はできてる**。

Now my question is whether person 4 is:

1. speaking for themselves (i.e. that they are ready for what might happen to them in this battle)
2. speaking for the 1000 / everyone.

At first I thought it was the second one, but then I was thinking, whether this is the way that this would be phrased if they were speaking for people other than themselves. Saying 覚悟はできてる and implying people other than yourself to me would be very assuming.  If they were speaking about other people I would have expected a だろう/はずだ.

Answer (score 2):

I think Person 4 is talking only about the speaker himself/herself. Plain 覚悟はできてる without any specific subject almost certainly means "***I*** am prepared". As you said, だろう/はずだ is needed if he/she is talking about someone else.